# Regex Pattern for 0 ,1 and an empty string

Tags: java, regex

Please help me with a pattern that matches exactly one occurences of 0,1 or an empty string.

Comment: do you want to have comma(`,`) in your pattern?

Comment: Do you *need* to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 8):

That's just a regex that optionally matches `0` or `1`.

```
/^[01]?$/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourstring.matches("([01]|^$)");
```

Comment: What is the `$^` supposed to match? I think you meant `^$` which would match the empty string.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant to put. Thanks for catching that.